# Laravel problem with error to get last 5 rows from database

Tags: php, laravel

I dont know where i can have problem. Simple problem: show last five rowns from database in blade view.

`database users:`

```
id | name | surrname |
1  | John | Smith    |
2  | Alex | Bimbo    |
```

`cobntroller:`

```
$lastFive = DB::table('users')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

`blade view:`

```
@foreach($lastFive => $lastFives)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $lastFives->id }}</td>                        
       <td>{{ $lastFives->name}}</td>
       <td>{{ $lastFives->surrname }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

`error:`

```
undefined offset: 1 {"userId":1, "exception":"[object]}
```

any advice how to figure out what im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is incorrect:

```
@foreach($lastFive => $lastFives)
```

change it to:

```
@foreach($lastFive as $lastFives)
```

Comment: you're right, typo

Comment: your welcome if this was helpful please mark it as the best answer